# vertical-align the text does not work with bootstrap class

Tags: css

I know how to vertical align the text by reducing the height of inner div and assigning it absolute positioning with top,bottom,left,right= 0,margin:auto  properties
I also know `display:flex` layout but it also does not work properly.
problem is `display:table` and `vertical-align` does not work properly with bootstrap classes. My div is simple i assigned it proper height , my inner div has reduced height so it should vertically align but it does not. I used bootstrap. I do not want to use absolute position to center it. Any idea?

```
<div class="col-sm-3" style="height:65px;display:table;vertical-align:middle;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle">abcabcabc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my div , i set its dimensions upon removing stuff, things worked out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using bootstrap, vertical align is done with "display: inline block"

```
.vcenter {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}
```

You can check here - http://plnkr.co/edit/vPKRjAf4wgtzJ7VVdOPN?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

what about using `line-height`? if `line-hight` is equal to its `hight` the text is centered vertically

```css
#test {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Test Text
</div>
```

Hope this helps